# how to get followers list from facebook account by graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

how to get followers list from facebook account by graph api?

I got friends from facebook account by

```
FB.api('/me/friends?access_token='+accessToken, {
                        fields : 'id, name, picture'
                    }, function(response) {
});
```

There is any way to get my Facebook account's followers?

Answer (score 5):

**OUTDATED ANSWER**

> You cannot get a user's subscribers as of API version 2.0

---

Yes there is. The User's who follow a particular User are his [subscribers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#subscribers), and the endpoint

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/subscribers
```

This will show you the total count if you don't have `user_subscriptions` or `friends_subscriptions` permission, if you have those you would get name and ids of the Users who follow a User.

Comment: This answer is now outdated. You cannot get a user's subscribers as of API version 2.0

Comment: Outdated, you will need an access token

Comment: `/<user_id>/subscribers` was removed after  April 30, 2015. So there is no way.

Comment: so what now? there is no way?

Answer (score 3):

Now in new version 2.0 subscribers has been remove in this version, but you can use v1.0 to get follows user

```
FB->api("v1.0/me/subscribers"); (Javas script);
```

require permission `user_subscribers` ...

Comment: I don't find `user_subcribers` permission and [Update Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/) says that `All API requests will behave as v2.0 API requests` after April 30, 2015.