# Facebook API: How can I find out the number of followers of a person (followed_by XXX)?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

On a Facebook profile, there is a listing of the number of people following this specific profile. (example: "Followed by 1,1159 people" )
However, I couldn't find neither in their open graph API documentation not in FQL docs how to retrieve this number programatically.
Note: there is an action called og.follows but it is related to the list of people this person follows (not the list of people following him).

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get followers list from facebook account by graph api?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276660/how-to-get-followers-list-from-facebook-account-by-graph-api)

Comment: Another case of terrible documentation on Facebook's side... apparently `followers == subscribers`... go figure :/