# How to get the Facebook followers or subscribers count for Graph API version 2.0?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am using Facebook Graph API version 2.0. I want to get the Facebook followers or subscribers count for some users. The complete Facebook page URL like: `https://www.facebook.com/XXXUsernamexxx` is with me.

I got a solution from [how to get followers list from facebook account by graph api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276660/how-to-get-followers-list-from-facebook-account-by-graph-api) that we can get the followers/subscribers count by using the following URL.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/{user-id}/subscribers
```

But I don't have user id with me. I can get the user id by sending first a request to Facebook API like: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/?ids={complete-facebook-page-url}`

From the response I will get the user id. Then there will be another request to Graph API to get the subscribers count. Hence there will be two requests to get the followers or subscribers count. But I want to limit it to one request.

It is possible to get the followers or subscribers count by sending complete Facebook page URL or by username?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find out how ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible as `user_subscriptions` is no longer available in v2.0.

Also currently for some 2.0 applications, the global ID seems to be still possible to use.

> We have to make some trade-offs while v1.0 and v2.0 are both in play but from April 30, 2015 we'll have a stricter separation between global and app-scoped IDs. -  [David Doyle](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/825306537512862/?qa_ref=pp&comment_id=825340900842759&offset=0&total_comments=3)

Comment: so what can we do now? is there really no way?