# How i can get number of followers for facebook user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Earlier i used [/{user-id}/subscribers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/subscribers), but after [update on April 30, 2015](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading) it was removed. Are there any other ways?

Answers from here is outdated [how to get followers list from facebook account by graph api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276660/how-to-get-followers-list-from-facebook-account-by-graph-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is no longer possible as indicated in the answer you linked.

Comment: why no, possible by parsing page by serverSideScripts (curl/php/perl e.t.c.)