# How to get facebook page followers count not likes?

Tags: facebook, get, deprecated, versions, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

Actually subscribers field is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher. So what can I use to get total page followers count instead that?

Comment: Nothing, the API does not provide that info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get followers list from facebook account by graph api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276660/how-to-get-followers-list-from-facebook-account-by-graph-api)